# How do I find the php exec command is done, so that I can use AJAX to rerender page?

Tags: php, ajax, exec

I have a slight problem. I'm working on a project that uses node.js to calculate some things. I use exec() function to make the node.js work. The calculation takes about 30 seconds and I would like to show some loading page until it's done.
The question is how can I test the calculation is done, so that I can rerender the page using AJAX?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you publish some code you have here

Answer (score 0):

Use exec with output argument, this will give you specified array filled with output of your command. You can find the execution complete on out put array.

Example :

exec('ls -la',$output);

print_r($output);

Output :

Array

(

```
[0] => total 16
[1] => drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2012-11-13 20:06 .
[2] => drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 2012-10-14 23:23 ..
[3] => -rw-r--r--  1 root root  177 2012-10-14 23:23 index.html
[4] => -rw-r--r--  1 root root  129 2012-11-13 20:06 index.php
```

)

You can also use fopen and fsockopen instead of exec.